# Helloellolloloo Worldorldrldldd

Tags: code-golf, string

Make a program that takes the word you input, and adds that word to the back of itself minus its first letter, then repeats until all letters are gone.  For example, `cat` would become `catatt`, and `hello` would become `helloellolloloo`.

**Input**
Any of the 26 letters of the English alphabet.  There may be multiple words separated by spaces, and the change should be applied to every word.

**Output**
The word(s) inputted, with each word put after itself with its first letter missing, and then with its second letter missing, and so on until there are no more letters to add.

**More examples:**

`ill eel` outputs `illlll eelell`

`laser bat` outputs `laserasersererr batatt`

`darth vader` outputs `dartharthrththh vaderaderdererr`

This is code golf, so the shortest code wins.

Clarification:
You can treat the input or output as a list.  You can separate words using newline instead of space.  You can add a trailing space to the input.

Comment: honestly, the multiple words thing is kinda annoying. All it does is require a split, apply the function on each word, and then join again. It's also quite debilitating for lots of esolangs which have to check for a space manually

Comment: Can I require a trailing space in the input?

Comment: sure, you can require a trailing space

Comment: Can we take in input as a list of words and output as such?

Comment: yes you can Quintec

Comment: What length words do you need to handle?

Comment: Is it OK for words to be separated by a newline in the output(instead of a space)?

Comment: Off topic, but FWIW, this is the exact output you would normally get when you type stuff on the new Macbook, the one with the butterfly keyboard.

Comment: Does it need to handle blank input

Comment: `1.` Please update the spec with the new allowances (array I/O, trailing space, etc.) `2.` Please inform the existing solutions in case any can save bytes by taking advantage of them.

Comment: Can the program take input on separate lines, one word per line?

Comment: Can we assume a word is not longer than the range of the native integer?

Comment: yes niedzejkob extra character

Comment: Hello, Welcome to PPCG! If you want to reply to a question asked by a commenter and ensure they're notified, you can use @. Also, as @Shaggy mentioned, make sure to edit the question with this new information to make sure it's always up-to-date.

Comment: @JoKing: so you only want simple puzzles and you're worried that you need 3 bytes more, 1 for splitting, 1 for looping and 1 for joining? Sorry, I implement in C# and I need 200 bytes just for keywords.

Comment: You never answered @MickyT's comment, is 9223372036854775807 characters as an upper limit for string length okay?

Comment: @BMO I thought there was a meta consensus that you didn't need to worry about reasonable implementation limits, but finding things again on meta is a black art.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Japt `-m`, <s>6</s> 3 bytes

Input and output are arrays of words.

```
£sY
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=o3NZ&input=WyJjb2RlIiwiZ29sZiJdCi1tUw==)

---

### Explanation

```
        :For each word in the input array
£       :Map each letter at index Y
 sY     :  Slice the current word from index Y
```

Comment: Thats really compact. Nice!

Comment: @qazwsx: Now 50% *more* compact!

Comment: Isn't `£` two bytes in UTF-8?

Comment: @Vi, I'm not using UTF-8 here.

Answer (score 38):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>60</s> 56 bytes

```
,[>++++++++[-<----<++++>>]<[>>]<[[<]>.[[-]>[.>]<[<]>]],]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYdBCoAgEAC/svfUFyz7kWUPJSuJoFEG/X7TaA7DzHauuaY7FjPHtPywRz/A2USC/IlRKDB7IQ7zx4o4MWsV@q7Q25EjtAT65KtrjQov)

Requires a trailing space and prints a leading space. Both of these could be circumvented, but that ends up at [112 bytes](https://tio.run/##VYtLCoAwDESv0n0/Jwi5SMhCS8UitKIVvH1MpS4cSJiZ5M3HlMtyxU3EEdoh8uBV0D0iA72LgJG8DoUeR@IBfKyegvbsxgtpYbv7kQ5ZpBbT1mRa3XM0dTHpzmdLJaYH).

#### Explanation

```
,[  Loop over each byte of input
  Tape: 32 w o r-32 d'
  >++++++++[-<----<++++>>]   Subtract 32 from the character and add 32 to the previous char
  Tape: 32 w o r d-32 0'
  <[>>]<   If the last character was a space
  Tape: 32 w o r d-32 0'
  or
  Tape: 32 w o r d' space-32
  [
    [<]>.   Move to the end of the word and print out the space
    [   Loop over each letter
      [-]    Remove the first letter (initially space)
      >[.>]  Print the rest of the word
      <[<]>  Move back to the first letter
    ]
    Tape: clear
  ]
,]  Get the next byte of input
```

Answer (score 20):

### Haskell, <s>36</s> 21 bytes

```
map$concat.scanr(:)""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcsxCoAwDADA3VeE0EFBfYDQl6hDiK0txrRY3291dj24QOVwItXbpZ6UDSdlusfCpFc7dYifRgULW2oA8hX1BgMeZgxfS7j@NIpgD@ic4Fof9kJ7qQPn/AI)

Edit: -15 bytes, because of new IO format (list of words instead of space separated words)

Comment: You could shave off 5 characters by replacing `scanr (:) ""` with `tails`.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: yes, but that would require an `import Data.List` which adds 17 bytes to the score.

Answer (score 19):

### Perl `-p`, <s>36</s> <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```perl
s!\b|\S!$'=~s/ .*//r!eg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YMSapJiZYUUXdtq5YX0FPS1@/SDE1/f9/j9ScnHyF8PyinJR/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

This is a single regsub. First, it matches all word boundaries or non-space characters:

```perl
[][H][e][l][l][o] [][W][o][r][l][d]
```

Note that each of these matches should be replaced with the rest of the word:

```perl
[→Hello][H→ello][e→llo][l→lo][l→o][o→] (...)
```

We can accomplish this with the special variable `$'`, which stores the part of the string after the match. However, we need to apply the nested regsub `s/ .*//` to it, which removes everything past the first space in `$'`, in order to get rid of the remaining words in the input.

Thanks to [@nwellnhof](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9296/nwellnhof) for 2 bytes.

Comment: You can replace `[^ ]` with `\S`.

Answer (score 19):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 49 bytes

```
d=lambda s:' '.join(n+d(n[1:])for n in s.split())
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##VcixCsJADADQ3a8IXZogFMSt4JeIQ0pOGom5IxcEv/50Enzja@/cq5/HkIvxcxOGvs4wL4@qjn4U9OtpvdG9BjioQ196M00kGi3UEwUnNYNSbCI6/M64l4CN82@FI3d4sZT4/vgA)

This takes advantage of the fact that `"".split()` returns an empty array so that acts as the check for the base case in the recursion.

Answer (score 17):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ḊƬ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjq5jax41rQEyNh1u9/7/Xz0lsagkQ6EsMSW1SB0A)

Don’t need the `K`s anymore since array input/output is now allowed.

```
ḊƬ€
  €   For each word:
Ḋ       Remove the first letter
 Ƭ      until there are none left.
```

Comment: I think you need `ḊƬẎ)` (or `ḊƬF)`, if you prefer).

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I don't think so. Each word is represented by a separate array in the output

Comment: I'm not sure if you can claim that, since the arrays are nested, and nothing is specified in the question to allow it.

Answer (score 14):

## JavaScript (ES6), 33 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @ShieruAsakoto*

I/O format: array of words.

```javascript
a=>a.map(g=w=>w&&w+g(w.slice(1)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcpBDoMgEADAex8iu7GS@AD8SONhhZXSbMUAkedTzo3nmQ9dlG0KZ5mO6LjtppFZSH/pBG@qWeow1NFD1VmCZZgRsdl45CisJXrY4aWCiHoqZlEr4uNfhTKn7huVW3eUyrv7Ra6/PtoP)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 35 bytes

I/O format: array of words.

```javascript
a=>a.map(w=>w.replace(/./g,"$&$'"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcpNDsIgEAbQvcdoGgeSSk9AL2JcfML0L2MhQNrjI2vj@r0dJ7JLWyyPI3ius62wE8wHUV12ukziKHCsRjMuQ9ffe@q0ri4cOQgbCYua1ZM2ERqIWeil9e1XBZlT8zfKX/dIZW1@wrfXRv0C)

Comment: 44: `s=>s.replace(/\S+/g,g=s=>s&&s+g(s.slice(1)))`

Comment: Thanks for my "something new" for today; never knew about `$'` (or `$<backtick>`).

Answer (score 14):

## APL(Dyalog), <s>19</s> 9 bytes

`{⌽∊,\⌽⍵}¨`

*thanks to @H.PWiz for jogging my brain*

This works because all strings in APL are character arrays.

```
{⌽∊,\⌽⍵}¨ 
        ¨ - for each string
      ⍵} - string argument - ex. "hello"
     ⌽ - reverse - "olleh"
   ,\ - scan magic - "o" "ol" "oll" "olle" "olleh"
  ∊ - enlist(join together) "oolollolleolleh"
{⌽ - reverse - "helloellolloloo"
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pRz95HHV06MSC6d2vtoRXYxDTUFdQfdcx41LngUVfbo65FmuoZqTk5@Qrl@UU5KepcxGjIzMlRSE3NIU5xTmJxapFCUmIJccpTEotKMhTKElNSi9QB)

Answer (score 13):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/),  <s>82</s> <s>75</s> 67 bytes

```r
write(sapply(x<-scan(,""),substring,1:(y=max(nchar(x))),y),1,y,,"")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrBCoAgDADQXwlPG6yD16iPWSoplMhmpV9v9M5Pxngl1QDKpZwd2jqr4wxkDJLeu1ZJ@SC7QN8ubpBdZIGGiNSRLHX65/AsNU4P@yDjAw)

*Several bytes saved thanks to [JayCe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80010/jayce)*

Separates output with newlines.

The `sapply(...)` expression generates a matrix/column vector of the appropriate substrings, padding with `""` as needed. `write` then prints the elements of the matrix, `y` per line, separating them with `""`.

Comment: Golfed a different approach while holding a sleepy baby; will add an explanation later.

Comment: If the length of the words are restricted, eg 99 chars or ~1e6 then you can knock of a bunch of bytes with `...substring,1:1e6,1e6)...` or similar

Comment: If you can separate words by a newline: [tio](https://tio.run/##DcoxDoAgDADArximNikDq8HHVCBqooS0qPB69OaTMV45agLlUs4OzVsNnIGMQdJ71SpH3sjN0L29uEEOOws0RKSO5KiTprL8e0SWuk8PxyTjAw). I have asked this in a comment. Can work with@MickyT ‘s comment

Comment: @JayCe looks like that could be [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcrBCoAgDADQXwlPG6yD16iPWSoplMhmpV9v9M5Pxngl1QDKpZwd2jqr4wxkDJLeu1ZJ@SC7QN8ubpBdZIGGiNSRLHX65/AsNU4P@yDjAw) before incorporating MickyT's suggestion

Answer (score 8):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>94</s> 93 bytes

```
-[-[-<]>>+<]>-<<+[[[-]<,[->+>+<<]>[-<+>]>>[-<->>+<]<]<<[>>+<<[-]]<[<]>[[.>]<[<]>[-]>]>>>>.<<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYtRCoAwDEOv0v/ZnaD0ImUfOiYOYROd4O1nJhJoQvK6nHMu6x333tkgCaoOh0WcmXGQyVgdOpSYnQKA84dBYiMJyCA2GPP6Jw4DVvX47b0WaluiVo8cqa6Unny1VGKiFw)

- Saved one byte thanks to [Nitrodon](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69059/nitrodon) -- golfing `.[-]>[.>]<[<]>` to `[.>]<[<]>[-]>`.

## Explanation

```
[[[ (dynamic) tape layout: ... NUL STR ... STR CHR FLG BUF SPC NUL ... ]]]

load a 32 into SPC
-[-[-<]>>+<]>-

while FLG
<<+[

 read a word
 [
  clear FLG; read CHR
  [-]<,
  copy CHR to BUF (using FLG as a temporary)
  [->+>+<<]>[-<+>]
  subtract SPC from BUF and save SPC
  >>[-<->>+<]
  move tape layout one to the right
  <
 ]

 strip trailing space; set FLG to true
 << [>>+<<[-]]
 to STR's first character
 <[<]>
 print word in all reduced forms
 [
  [.>]<[<]>[-]>
 ]

 print SPC; move to FLG
 >>>>.<<
]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVC7TsMwFN39FWejVUkG2KjlgUqFoUKoj8nK4DpOa5HEke1Q8vXh2mVAkRLH597zOntl@2bUX/MspcSinnrVWb1EVINBqyY3xheUZYmP0w6H4z6f03fzvsd294bX0xaHz03GE1ZVFWOtUzUUnp9g@@gSzgpJD6@EWNGrYOx2ta1JDIzzlWQM3uSdm/M1g2SAbo3yaWJ9x0iRbmVR8ceEumHKJog/eViMwfaXbEkF4ommG5xXflrmJbEiYVImDytR0VUYz9ErHbP5xrsus6i@RlDfJlsGRJovsmf66xwB/4qB602Sj1cDby/XSDOcgfIjRG8HkIBtk6swKG3WCCZmg2nHj4aBc8jEzikVKaSqjvuHgMb6EKGvKjk0ngYleWcYPPWZK6JiodqWmqlHbWo0znfh3pssRZXniVTc7dz3KNP6L4TLzVM@IUrOWTXPrs85ohushmtgfmyIptcGvw)

## Attribution

Esolang's [brainfuck constant collection](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_constants#32) was used for the initial space load.

Comment: This doesn't seem to terminate. Is that intended?

Comment: @JoKing Yes. In certain implementations it would exceed the tape limit, exiting by error.

Answer (score 6):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>6</s> 4 bytes

<sup>-2 bytes thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan) (taking input as a list)!</sup>

```
moΣṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Pzf/3OKHO1f///8/WiknsTi1SElHKSmxRCkWAA)

#### Explanation

Takes input as a list of strings and maps the following function:

```
Σṫ  -- example argument: "abc"
 ṫ  -- tails: ["abc","bc","c"]
Σ   -- concat: "abcbcc"
```

Comment: The split & join are possibly no longer required, currently such specification is in a comment.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
€.síJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/q9v9R0xq94sNrvf7r/I9WSk4sUYrlilbKSM3JyQezMnNylHQUlFJTc8DcnMTi1CKQQBJUZUpiUUkGSKAsMQUoEwsA)

**Explanation**

```
€.s        # push suffixes of each
   í       # reverse each
    J      # join suffixes
```

Comment: Boring 5-bytes alternative: [`í€ηJí`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/q9v/w2kdNa85t9zq89r/O/2il5MQSpViuaKWM1JycfDArMydHSUdBKTU1B8zNSSxOLQIJJEFVpiQWlWSABMoSU4AysQA) (since prefixes is a 1-byte builtin instead of 2-bytes like suffixes; still requires an additional reverse-each however at the start however, so the byte-count remains 5).

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 15 bytes

```
 
¶
.
$&$%'
¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fgevQNi49LhU1FVV1EFPh//@UxKKSDIWyxJTUIgA) Note: trailing spaces. Explanation:

```
 
¶
```

Split on spaces.

```
.
$&$%'
```

Append its suffix to each letter. The `%` means that we only get the word's suffix.

```
¶
```

Join with spaces.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org/), 47 bytes (38 key strokes)

Start with your input as the sole line in a Vim buffer.

```
:s/<Space>/\r/g<CR>ggqaywPlxqqb99@aj0q99@bgg99J
```

### Explanation

This puts each word on its own line, iterates over each line, then rejoins them all. Breaks if words are longer than 99 characters or if your input has more than 99 words.

1. `:s/<Space>/\r/g<CR>` [replaces](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace) spaces with new lines (`\r`)
2. `gg` positions the cursor at the beginning of the first line
3. `qa` begins recording [macro](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros) *a*:

   - `yw` yanks the rest of the word
   - `P` [puts it behind the cursor](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#P)
   - `lx` removes the first letter of the latter word
   - `q` stops recording macro *a*
4. `qb` begins recording macro *b*:

   - `99@a` executes macro *a* ninety-nine times (introduces the character limit)
   - `j0` positions the cursor at the start of the next line
   - `q` stops recording macro *b*
5. `99@b` executes macro *b* ninety-nine times (introduces the word limit)
6. `gg` positions the cursor at the first line
7. `99J` [joins](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#J) the following ninety-nine lines with spaces (word limit again)

For another 2 bytes (2 key strokes) you could extend the word limit to 999. Another 4 bytes, 9999, etc.

Answer (score 5):

## [Pepe](//github.com/Soaku/Pepe/), <s>167</s> 153 bytes

```
REEerEeeEeeeeeRrEEEEerEEEEEeerEErEEeerreErEEeErreEREEEEEEEreereErEerEEEErEEeerrEEreRRErEEEEreREEreeereReeRerEEEEEErEEEeerreEerEEeerEEEEerEEeEreereErEeree
```

[Try it online!](//soaku.github.io/Pepe/#T!8g--gE0E!k@A!m@AE7*AC!q!k@E$-&!q$FG$/.&2-c@K!k-g!m*AC*)

Answer (score 5):

## 16-bit x86 assembly code, 24 bytes

```
     47             inc    di
     B020           mov    al,20h
l1:  3806           cmp    [si],al
     7212           jb     l5 ;less means end of string
     7401           je     l2  ;equal means space was seen
     4F             dec    di ;overwrite extra space
l2:  E80300         call   l3
     46             inc    si ;move to next character in word
     75F1           jne    l1
l3:  56             push   si
l4:  3806           cmp    [si],al
     A4             movsb      ;copy character
     77FB           ja     l4  ;until either zero or space is seen
     5E             pop    si
l5:  C3             ret
```

Call with si = pointer to source string, di = pointer to output buffer.
The source string requires a zero byte to end it.
The code is the same in 16- or 32- or 64-bit (si/di become either esi/edi or rsi/rdi).
32-bit code is two bytes larger because of the expanded call.
64-bit code is three bytes larger still because the inc/dec of rsi/rdi attracts a prefix (but if it is known that they are within 32-bit memory space, then they can be esi/edi again to avoid that penalty).

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
"@gXH"HX@Jh)]0&h
```

Input is a cell array of words. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X8khPcJDySPCwStDM9ZALeP//2r1nMTi1CJ1BfWkxBL1WgA)

#### Explanation

```
"         % Implicit input: cell array of strings. For each cell
  @g      %   Push content of current cell, that is, a word
  XH      %   Copy into clipboard H
  "       %   For each letter
    H     %     Push word
    X@    %     Push iteration index
    Jh)   %     Index from that until the end into current word
  ]       %   End
  0       %   Push 0. Will be cast to char. Char(0) is displayed as space
  &h      %   Concatenate horizontally all elements so far. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 4):

## [K4](http://kx.com/download) / [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 9 bytes

**Solution:**

```
,/'(1_)\'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X0dfXcMwXjNGXUMpJbGoJEPJWqksMSW1SEnz/38A)

**Explanation:**

```
,/'(1_)\' / the solution
        ' / apply to each
       \  / scan
   (  )   / do this together
    1_    / drop first
,/'       / flatten (,/) each (')
```

Answer (score 4):

## [C++ (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 174 bytes

```cpp
#include<map>
#include<string.h>
std::string r(std::string w){while(auto x=strchr(w.c_str(),32))return r(w.substr(0,x-w.c_str()))+" "+r(x+1);return w!=""?w+r(w.substr(1)):w;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY5BbsIwEEX3OYVrNh4FUGl3iUmPUhnbwpYmTjSxcSTE2UMoVYTYZDf/zZvR132/06jCeZo2PmhMxspW9U2xpCGSD@e9a4ohmqp6RkbiNWW4ZufRCpVix8bjjLUjkff6dx4FbL@/AMjGRIE98JBOD/65HXeLA1ByxksSY3mA@l/OH0fOf3L5cnQAqHJ9W@oy6buZW9U2hQ@RtcoHAddnW92lKKUgwT0isxY5gJR/KxsM1u8WqsESO6m44hlF0bGLMpZWTL36y1nE7t25TXc)

It's my first submission, and i didn't know if returning string instead of printing it is okay :)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Yes, returning a string is okay. Hope you stick around!

Comment: You could use the inequality operator's symmetry to remove a space and thus save a byte -- `return w!=""?` can be `return""!=w?`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 3 bytes

```
m|]
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=m%7C]&i=darth%0Avader&a=1)

Explanation:

```
m   Map over the lines
 |] Get all suffixes (suffices?)
    Implicit flatten and output
```

Comment: Regarding _suffices_: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suffices#Etymology_2

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
ƛ[Ḣx+
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C6%9B%5B%E1%B8%A2x%2B&inputs=%5B%27laser%27%2C%27bat%27%5D&header=&footer=)

(IMO) this is a really neat recursive solution. Port of my JS answer that came out really nicely.

```
ƛ     # Foreach value as n
 [    # If truthy (Not empty string)
   x  # Call this function (The function we're mapping with)
  Ḣ   # With n[1:] - remove first character
    + # Appended to the result
```

The "concatenation of suffixes" approach doesn't do any better:

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
ƛṘ¦∑Ṙ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C6%9B%E1%B9%98%C2%A6%E2%88%91%E1%B9%98&inputs=%5B%27laser%27%2C%27bat%27%5D&header=&footer=)

```
ƛ     # Map...
 Ṙ    # Reverse
  ¦   # Cumulative sums (prefixes)
   ∑  # Concatenated
    Ṙ # Reversed
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
⪫Ｅ⪪Ｓ ⭆ι✂ιμＬι¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYpBCoAgEEX3nUJajVCL1p2gKAg8waCSA2YiU9efjNp8/uM9G7DYE6PIVigxzCclWDGDyZEYppQvNlzVDrpTrWrrfvxGVCGS9e85OrX4tHMAqs2g9d/rUcRh4aBudL400t/xAQ) Note: Trailing space. Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   Ｓ            Input string
  ⪪             Split on spaces
 Ｅ              Map over each word
      ι         Current word
     ⭆          Map over each character and join
        ι       Current word
         μ      Current index
           ι    Current word
          Ｌ     Length
            ¹   Literal 1
       ✂        Slice
⪫               Join with spaces
                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-s`, 11 bytes

```
J_@>,#_Mq^s
```

Takes the space-separated list of words from stdin. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fK97BTkc53rcwrvj//5zE4tQihaTEkv@6xQA)

#### Explanation

```
             s is space (implicit)
        q    Read a line of stdin
         ^s  Split it on spaces
       M     Map this lambda function to each word:
 _            The word...
  @>          sliced starting at index...
    ,#_       range(len(word))
              This creates len(word) slices ["word" "ord" "rd" "d"]
J             Join those into a single string
             The resulting list of modified words is printed; the -s flag uses space
             as the separator
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 63 bytes

```python
lambda s:' '.join(map(g,s.split()))
g=lambda s:s and s+g(s[1:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcrBCsIwDADQ@74ityQoAz0O9iXqIaNdV8m60gTBr6@34fXx6te3o9z7Oj@7yr4EAZsQcHwfudAuldLVRquanZh5SPO5DKQEsEsie9ymF/facnFYCbMqxKjIw0kqFhss4v8YpPkGHwmxIfcf)

Comment: It is 64 bytes on my computer, mac OS.

Answer (score 3):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
±［±］⇵］
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JUIxJXVGRjNCJUIxJXVGRjNEJXUyMUY1JXVGRjNE,i=JTVCJTIybGFzZXIlMjIlMkMlMjAlMjJiYXQlMjIlNUQ_,v=8)

[5 bytes](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JUIxJXVGRjNCJXVGRjNEJXVGRjNEJUIx,i=JTVCJTIybGFzZXIlMjIlMkMlMjAlMjJiYXQlMjIlNUQ_,v=8) with a crazy output format

Answer (score 3):

## C#, <strike>111</strike> 90 bytes

```
b=>string.Join(" ",(b.Split(' ').Select(x=>string.Concat(x.Select((y, i)=>x.Substring(i))))))
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##hZDBSgMxEIbveYphL01gDXheW5CCgiiILXgQD9PssBtMkzXJlhbps69po3UpFP9DwvzzzTAzKlwp52nog7YNLHYh0rpi40jOnTGkonY2yHuy5LU6Ix61/TyzlrSN51brCetkyCWGj1AxZnFNoUNFME/NnaHbrrtmXwySlMEQ4Nm7xuP66GT/oBAxagUbp2t4Qm15iD71fXsH9E0QJ@6v4qC73qqbTJaQ/xkgTIfVdJZD@eBSswKKkq/kojM68glMhFzQ4QB8e@LSuAqT8ZvhuxK0mM6S0a8yw7U4akh7jqf42VS@eh0pHY448qIlY1whRPU/WqOPLWywJn@x4CXd@ciP8nuW3z0bvgE)

By Changing input and output to arrays, I saved a few bytes:

```
b=>b.Select(x=>string.Concat(x.Select((y,i)=>x.Substring(i)))).ToArray()
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##nVGxasMwEN31FYcnG1xB59SGEGihtFAaQ4fS4SIfsagjpZKSxgR/u3uJ49Z4yNA3CN27p6d7kvI3yjrqdl6bNSwbH2gzE@NKLmxdkwraGi8fyJDTaqJ40uZrQhV0CFOqcoQlE7JA/@lnQhjckN@iIliwua1pvt3eiqMAhqrRe3hxdu1wc2Z6/gQfMGgFe6tLeEZtYh8c@75/ALq1T351fydOuN8ZdTcoUxh2OSBk0K2yfCWXdEoaH7K873J2o5CJoRM3qU6ynOvdqpfEOmHIws6dwyZOOs41vvWSTL45HYgfii7DykfLg0cQpRgb@ubZjxBVVNc2gpYdZ/93KdGFKkoh2mNJ7prdK3/I2W3Ub0W/tqL7AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>17</s> 13 bytes

```
{,/|:'|,\|x}'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P81KSUFJv1pHv8ZKvUYnpqaiVv1/moKGUmZOjpK1UmoqiMxJLE4tAtJJiSVAMiWxqCQDSJclpgBFNf8DAA)

Prefix anonymous function; Input is taken as a list of strings, which in turn are lists of characters.

Thanks @streetster for 4 bytes.

#### How:

```
{,/|:'|,\|x}' //Main function, argument x → ("ill";"eel")
            ' // For each element of the argument
         |x}  // Flip it. x → ("lli";"lee")
       ,\     // Concatenate each element, keeping intermediates. x → (("l";"ll";"lli");("l";"le";"lee")
      |       // Flip it again. x → (("lli";"ll";"l");("lee";"le";"l"))
   |:'        // Now flip each element. x → (("ill";"ll";"l");("eel";"el";"l"))
{,/           // Concatenation scan. x → ("illlll";"eelell")
```

Comment: You can return a list, also take a look at my [oK](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172466/69200) solution

Comment: @streetster oh, nice. I'm still in the process of learning K, so my solutions won't be as short or as elegant as I'd like. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Flatten before reverse allows you to omit the "reverse-each", bringing it down to 10 bytes:  `{|,/,\|x}'`

Answer (score 3):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 179 bytes

```lisp
(defun r(s)(cond((endp s)nil)((eql(first s)#\Space)(princ " ")(r(rest s)))(t(q s)(r(rest s)))))(defun q (l)(cond((eql(first l)#\Space)t)((endp l)t)(t(princ(first l))(q(rest l)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9LDgIxDEOvEpUFznnYskFtRlSK@kmLOP4QZlDFzrGjZzlqHm3fkWR7FTIMRqwlAVJSo8ElK/vRFVu2Md253G/tEYXRLJdIgQLDYHKEzJjoLv4tN098J@jiL6Qu5ORfr37lPBvWF6OfTD2Yu1fEKhaFwlNUK72raQp09UnT8w8)

This is my first try at golfing any edits are welcome

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG. Removing whitespace can [save you 29 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY9BCgMhDEWvInbRn/N0282gGSoER6NDj2/TWmR2Py/hfRIktTIGIu9ndopGCEeOAOdYXKOchGyo5ybYk7Zu7PZ8lC0woWjKwTtPUCj/dkToqBauyOD0V8jyX5SylJ3@zfKNfTasK0KdUplSNRdrYP9ikcO9D5Xo7/ZRJxrjAw).

Comment: @Johnathan Frech thanks i just updated with no spaces

Comment: I think you missed four superfluous spaces.

Comment: You can most likely also use `car` instead of `first` and `cdr` instead of `rest` to further golf your submission.

Comment: Na, im good with it now haha, maybe ill come back and mess with it later. Im just learning lisp now my teacher said to never use car and cdr so they were out of my head while i was doing it

Comment: Well, one has not truly done list processing without using these two primitives. :P

Comment: (1) you can use `eql` instead of `equal`, even `eq` seems to work in TIO. (2) The `(r(coerce "hello world" 'list))` is testing, not part of the byte count. (Testing is usually put in the TIO footer section.)

Comment: Oh, I also think `nil` is redundant.

Comment: I just edited, i thought eql would test reference thats why i had equal but eql works

Answer (score 3):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 70 bytes

```lua
for i=1,#arg do x=arg[i]for i=1,#x do io.write(x:sub(i))end print()end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/Lb9IIdPWUEc5sShdISVfocIWyIjOjIWLV4BEM/P1yosyS1I1KqyKS5M0MjU1U/NSFAqKMvNKNEDM////Z6Tm5OT/L88vykkBAA)

#### Explanation

The arguments in Lua are stored in the table `arg` starting at index 1. The unary operator `#` returns the size of the table and function `s:sub(a,b)` returns a substring
based on string `s` delimited by integers `a` and `b`, if b is not passed it will return the rest of the string.

I had to use `io.write()` instead of `print()` to avoid line breaking, and added `print()` at the end for the opposite reason.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>79</s> 74 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to mypetlion*

```python
print(*map(lambda x:''.join(x[n:]for n in range(len(x))),input().split()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchBDkBADADAr/SmFXFx8xVxWLGoVNusFbx@OU0y/ubNtCvFE2vG@giOEo5pDvD0VdXuxorPoP24WAIFVkhB14gS/yeihtWvjNSeLvxLVMoWRQxuSzJ/)

A full program that takes input from stdin and outputs to stdout.

Comment: `print(*map(lambda x:''.join(x[n:]for n in range(len(x))),input().split()))` Full program to save 5 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>44</s> 32 bytes

*-12 bytes thanks to nwellnhof!*

```perl6
~*.words>>.&{[~] $_,{S/.//}...0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv05Lrzy/KKXYzk5PrTq6LlZBJV6nOlhfT1@/Vk9Pz6D2vzVXcWKlQpqGekZqTk6@AlBxToq65n8A)

An anonymous Whatever lambda that takes a string and returns a string.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
 *.words   # Split the given word by spaces
        >>.&{                  }  # Map each word to
                           ...  # A list composed of
                 $_              # The initial string
                   ,{S/.//}      # Remove the first character
                              0  # Until it's empty
             [~]   # All joined together
~   # Convert the list to a string, which joins by spaces
```

Comment: [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzrYKj06plw71ja6LlZBRV@nOlhfT1@/Vk9Pz6D2vzVXcWKlQpqGekZqTk6@Qnl@UU6KuuZ/AA)

Comment: @nwellnhof I can't believe I forgot about `.words`!

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 79 bytes

```c
f(s,t)char*s,*t;{for(;*s;printf("%.*s",*s^32?t?t-s:~0:1,s),s++)t=strchr(s,32);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYzBCoMwEAXP9StCoJDEWFq9GYp/UkhjbIRUZXfbi9hfT0NvxdtjhnmuejiX0iBQk3TBgkKtyKzDDMIoNAuMEw2CH08KuVZ4a@qOOqqw/Zzbi0apsSwlXZHABcgvTS3NlnLEnnachCzW4pD74GOcuTRseREKntcPjzEy7@NeRIse2N3SXvUWKLC37T38yy19AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 42 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.map{|a|(w=a.b).chars{a[0]='';w<<a}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664ulgvN7GguiaxRqPcNlEvSVMvOSOxqLg6Mdog1lZd3brcxiaxtrb2f4FCWnS0ukdqTk6@uo56eX5RTop6bOx/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 33 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/\B(?=(\S+))/g,"$1")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bclBCsJADADAu69YitAEtcUHrIJf8NpL3E1bJTQlWerzV8/iXOdFG3my51pOi2auY6weL94Zr0KJoR9ucI0w3A@I/XRs9ucGa9LFVbgTnWCEdmYRDW81yS3i7meFnC08qPy5TFbmsFFm@279AA)

I don't really know JavaScript, but I just copied [Arnauld's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172398/75057) syntax with an idea I had for the regex substitution :P

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 6 bytes

```
ÆÅ_╞↑
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7//9w2@HW@EdT5z1qm6jw/3@0UkpiUUmGko5SWWJKapFSLAA)

Outputs a trailing space, though you can add another byte to remove this.

<s>Hopefully 6 bytes when implicit input is implemented.</s> Yay.

#### Explanation:

```
        Implicit input
Æ       Implicit for loop over the next 5 instructions
 Å  ↑   While true without popping (empty string is false)
  _╞    Duplicate the top of stack and remove the first letter
        (space) Append a space to the stack
        Implicitly output the stack joined together
```

Comment: I can confirm that `ÆÅ_╞↑ ` works in the latest version of MathGolf, with input `['Hello','world']`. It is to be pushed today. I've worked on getting typed input and implicit input working properly, and now I can run the program above with correct output.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 90 bytes

```java
s->{var r="";for(var x:s){for(int i=0;i<x.length();)r+=x.substring(i++);r+=" ";}return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDBbsIwDL3zFVYlpGSUaGdCOe62E8dph0BTCISkst2uCPXbs7Rsh2kHy35@9nuWL6Y360t9Te7WRmS4ZKw6dl696MW/XtOFI7sYJvLoDRG8GxfgsQBou4N3RyA2nFMfXQ23zIk9owunj08weCI5jwK8/ehsf9nyWeyggSrRevfoDQJWRaGbiGICw4bkYwIuMLjqVbvtoLwNJz4LqSWuqkFRd6BZR7jVSurcK6DQI1ruMADqMenZfpJ5GgJb4s2f2wD2d2J7U7Fj1eYhbkSxpA0saRmKct4ooVGmbf1dTEhR6x2L7CWlfDqMiynGlM7W@whfEX2dnPdgrU/5cRbhYDjVBvkMvaktfgM)

### Credits

- -11 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen), notifying me of the rule change about the input.

Comment: `s.split(" ")` can be just `s`. The rules have been changes, so you can take a String-array as input. (I also tried modifying the input array so you can remove the return-statement, but it seems to be longer.)

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, <s>29</s> 23 bytes

Port of [Javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172398/80745) by @Arnauld

```powershell
$args-replace'.',"$&$'"
```

Input and output are a list of word. Test script:

```powershell
$f = {

$args-replace'.',"$&$'"

}

@(
    ,('illlll eelell', 'ill','eel')
    ,('laserasersererr batatt', 'laser','bat')
    ,('dartharthrththh vaderaderdererr', 'darth','vader')
) | % {
    $e,$s = $_
    $r = &$f @s
    $r = "$r"
    "$($r-eq$e): $r"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True: illlll eelell
True: laserasersererr batatt
True: dartharthrththh vaderaderdererr
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 97 bytes

Scala main that takes a single String argument containing all the words.

```scala
args(0).split(" ").foreach(x=>{for(i<-0 to x.length)print(x.substring(i,x.length));print(" ")})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcxNCsMgEEDhfU4xZDVCK9n3B3qAHsKYqVpExZlSIeTsNqXQ3YMPHlsTTc/zk6zA3YQE1ITSwnArZe2mOsZJaS4xCI4wKv3IlYz12C7XdW8M5@MEkqHpSMmJV6WGJNg0v2aWvR2Gwx/V6cff1aaGoW@9e4oxwzvXuHwA)

Comment: That's actually 95 bytes, if you remove the unnecessary newlines.

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, 86 bytes

Reduced a lot, thanks to @ElPedro and @manatwork

```
def f(a):return a+f(a[1:])if''<a else'' 
for x in input().split():print(f(x),end=' ')
```

P.S. I tried removing split but then nothing is printing, its probably required in python3

Comment: The question asks for multiple words. Also, you should include your bytecount in the answer

Comment: oh my bad will correct it

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can use [tryitonline](https://tio.run) to format your answer nicely and allow people to test it. See [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172436/56555) as an example.

Comment: And TIO has a character counter too, which will say your solution currently has “106 chars, 106 bytes (UTF-8)”. BTW, unfortunately your code have a small glitch as for “cat” outputs “catat”, not “catatt”. Just change the condition to `len(a)>0`. Or to `a>''` as it is shorter. Or to `''<a` as that way you need no space between the `if` keyword and the expression. See [Tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python).

Comment: You don't need the space in the `split()`. Python splits on space by default. You can also remove the space in `return ''` to save another one.

Comment: You also don't need the newline and two spaces before `return a+f(a[1:])`. It can go on the same line as the `if`. With these and the hints from @manatwork you should be well below 100 :-)

Comment: Don't remove the whole `split` - just the space in it. [Try this link](https://tio.run/##JcjBCkIhEEbhvU/x78ahCKKd1L43aBEtBB0SZJTJC7enNyE4cODr3/FuepkzZYH4yMGhCNE1BstjM0U8LH6ew4sd/kQEwEkz7Ci66tvwfPr0WtZDt6LDi9/5mDXdCMRz3nOtDY9mNf0A "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: You can also replace the `if` and 2 `return`s with `return a+f(a[1:])if''<a else''` which can then go on the same line as `def f(a)` taking it down to [87 bytes](https://tio.run/##DccxCsMwDEDRvafQJouWQulm0r036BA6GCwRg5CN4kB6etfw4fHbr2/VnmNkFpCQKDr3ww3Sdd76iF8qgrgkYN0ZEQAuUh1OKDZrRw9035uWaWxerAcJJ93Y8gsBaYw3q1b4VNf8Bw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 58 bytes

Takes a space-separated string of words from `stdin` and returns `stdout` likewise.

```
f=lambda x:x and x+f(x[1:])
print(*map(f,input().split()))
```

It works by splitting the string into a list of words and using `map()` to call the recursive function `f` on each element. Honestly, I don't know exactly how `f` works. When the stack reaches the end of the word, `x` becomes the empty string (`''`), so the `and` statement returns `False`, which I suspect acts as the base case to end recursion.

Here's the same idea but without the [functional](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html) aspects:

```
def f(x):
    return x and x + f(x[1:])

print(*( f(word) for word in input().split() ))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [q](http://kx.com/download) <strike>78</strike> 38 bytes

```
" "sv{r::x;{x,r::1_r}/[count x;x]}each
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can take input as a list of lines and return a list of lines rather than having to use vs and sv to split on whitespace.

Comment: Oh right, I thought the multiple words necessitated a string split, I`ll give it another go, thank you

Comment: Also... take a look at the [scan](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/control/#scan) operator rather than recursing.

Comment: ... was thinking along the lines of `{ raze {1_x} scan x } each` which can be golfed down a little more...

Comment: Used 'over' instead with some recursion, need to find a way to do it without globals

Comment: `" "sv{raze{1_x}scan x}each`, your one, comes out to 26, gonna be hard to beat that

Comment: `raze@'((1_)\)@'` for 15 bytes :)

Comment: @streetster `raze@'(1_)\'` should work too

Comment: @ngn `raze@'((1_)\')` works for 14 bytes, need the brackets else q complains about the naked \. Can also do `(,/')((1_)\')` for 13.

Answer (score 2):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 28 bytes

```
Join&sp##Sum@Suffixes=>Split
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NczBCsIwEATQe79iScVTv0CoCF7EgwgRPIQc1mZjAmsbkq3497Einds8mEERHAJVD7se6nmK47akttXz66Bn7@OHSr/XiaPUC5ErZpPS8LTNNcdRblTkiIWK8R2YBpaoEzFPcJ8yO9X9KTIDEa@Vl0WGB8oKDrMEeKOjvNKAAuH3pBpr6xc)

### Alternatives

```
ReplaceF&(Sum@Suffixes)&/"\\w+"               ?? 31 bytes
ReplaceF«_,/"\\w+",Sum@Suffixes»              ?? 34 bytes, 32 chars
ReplaceF<~_,/"\\w+",Sum@Suffixes~>            ?? 34 bytes
```

### Explanation

```
Join&sp##Sum@Suffixes=>Split    input, e.g.: "abc defg"
                       Split    split the input on spaces
                                e.g.: ["abc", "defg"]
                     =>         on each word:
                                  e.g.: "abc"
             Suffixes             take the suffixes of that word
                                  e.g.: ["abc", "bc", "c"]
         Sum@                     join them together
                                  e.g.: "abcbcc"
       ##                       then
Join&                           join the result by:
     sp                           spaces
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 81 bytes

```scala
def e(s:List[String])=s.map(_.foldRight(("","")){(a,b)=>(a+b._1,a+b._1+b._2)}._2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYwxC8IwEIXn5leETHdYCjoWKrg56KKIg0i5trFG0qQkWaT0t8cUEXzDu8fxvedb0hRt85Jt4EdShk0s6@SDDykDud6XfOccvW/n4JTp71jyi1GBVyxLJE8a0z9oAxIOyocfB2IvtbYiF1frdCcQkWUzi8u2BF/@s1j5YqAR6uJhdXdS/TMAiFRNrQkob7DaAq2aol7n37PYBufF4hw/)

As per comments, this can receive and output a `List[String]`. This builds the output from right to left, starting with the rightmost letter, then prepending the two rightmost letters, and so on down the line.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
m_s.__
```

<sub>Decreased byte(s?) thanks to @Steven H.</sub>

[Try it online!](//tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Pze@WC8@/v//aKWcxOLUIiUdpaTEEqVYAA) Input and output are a list.

Expalanation:

```
        - implicit output
m       - map function d:
      _ -   ...d reversed...
    ._  -   ...get all prefixes of it...
  _s    -   ...joined and reversed
        - ...over implicit Q (input)
```

Comment: You can save a byte by using `m` instead of `V`, since that would make the `Q` implicit rather than explicit.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), 129 bytes

```pascal
var s:string;i,j:int32;begin read(s);repeat j:=Pos(' ',s);for i:=1to j do write(s[i..j-1]);write(' ');Delete(s,1,j)until s=''end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcqxDsIgEIDhV7mNktAm1Q3SQa27u3Gg5docIdBwVB8fa1y//98szza0yzbX@rYZWHPJFFdDymuK5XwyE64UIaN1DUuTcUNbwOvhkbgRINSBS8pAeuhLAg8uwSdTwYaf1HW@7V/S/OG4pRkx4C@qXnm5x0IBeBACo@tqtdPsEC7X23iHJe1AIQBigC8)

Requires that the input ends in space, allowed in [this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/172391/helloellolloloo-worldorldrldldd?page=1&tab=oldest#comment415959_172391).

Answer (score 2):

## Twig, 73 bytes

Creates a macro with the function `f()` that receives an array of words, displaying the words separated by new lines.

```
{%macro f(a)%}{%for v in a%}{%for i in 0..v|length%}{{v[i:]}}{%endfor%}
{%endfor%}{%endmacro%}
```

To use it, just import:

```
{% import 'macro.twig' as a %}

{{ a.f(['a','sentence','is','a','list','of','words']) }}

{# to pass a string, you can split it #}
{{ a.f('a sentence is a list of words'|split(' ')) }}
```

You can try it on https://twigfiddle.com/8xech1
**Warning**: due to the way that output is handled in the link, I was forced to add a simple period (`.`) at the end of the line. This is ***NOT*** needed for normal operation.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
{a₁ᶠc}ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/vzrxUVPjw20Lkmsfbp3w/3@0UnJ@SqqSjlJ6fk6aUuz/KAA)

#### Explanation

```
{    }ᵐ          Map for each word:
 a₁ᶠ               Find all suffixes
    c              Concatenate into a single string
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 24 bytes

This solution is not optimal in two ways: *1)* [the other Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172396/48198) by [nimi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34531/nimi?tab=profile) is *3* bytes shorter and *2)* the input is limited to 9223372036854775807 characters (*~36* exabytes), though I think it's an interesting find:

```hs
map.mconcat$drop<$>[0..]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxNC4JAGITv/oohPCjiEoE39eK1QOgSVMSmrx@07srumv8@e6nL8DDzMIN0L1Jq61Dgtk1yFlNjdCN92Foz52F53QtxyLI7b6NmiZXTA9G8@LO3Rw2B3sScatTkUOQ5evKV0Z60d1gHshSAHfAIN5iVIUmwQ1pyMP26aNGrsa3jow4h/uzibVQKRCpQ0pHFU/qgldYPeMuW7KfplOzdll6quv4C) (sets a limit of *255* characters for TIO would time out otherwise)

#### Explanation

Since `drop` has type `Int -> [a] -> [a]` it forces `[0..]` to be `[0..9223372036854775807]` which is finite and thus the program terminates (eventually).

And `mconcat` takes the list of `[drop 0, drop 1..]` and gives us a function `String -> String` which is equivalent to:

```hs
\str-> drop 0 str ++ drop 1 str ++ .. ++ drop 9223372036854775807 str
```

<sub>**Note:** Once the argument of `drop` is greater or equal to the length of `str` it just appends empty strings.</sub>

### Practical solution, 40 bytes

This won't take as long as the shorter solution but at a great cost of *16* bytes:

```hs
map$mconcat=<<map drop.zipWith pure[0..]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5BC4JAEIXv/opHeFBE6QdoF68FQoeCith01KV1d9ldE/rx2VCXxzdv3jxmFP5JSq09KlzXSdh4ao1uRajKkid0ztjiLe1JhhF2dnTZFsWNg1LzBScOdyR2Dsfg9hoFBpOyKqnJgyswUKiNDqSDxzKSowicAS/hR7MwZBk2yHcsTD8vmfViXOe5qEeMP/t0lUqBSEVKeHJ4iBB1wvFbL9GR@7S9EoNf83PdNF8)

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <s>193</s> 166 bytes

```cs
class a{static void Main(string[]b){foreach(var c in b)d(c,0);}static void d(string c,int e){if(e==c.Length)Console.Write(" ");else{Console.Write(c[e++..]);d(c,e);}}}
```

[Try it Online!](http://rextester.com/SOJAG62582)

Since .NET automatically splits the arguments at spaces, it's possible to loop over them without splitting them manually.
Other than that, this uses recursion to subtract one character at a time using the overload of `string.Substring` that takes only 1 argument which is the index to start at.

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 8 bytes

```
{iS\[}ww
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/OjM4Jrq2vPz/f4/UnJx8hfL8opwUAA)

```
{
 iS # All suffixes
 \[ # Concatenate
}ww # For each word
```

Answer (score 2):

## APOL, 23 bytes

`ƒ(s(i) j(ƒ(∋ V(⋒ ∈)))))`

### Explanation

```
ƒ(         List-builder for loop
  s(       String-split instruction (splits at spaces by default)
    i      Input
  )
  j(       String join instruction
    ƒ(     List-builder for loop
      ∋    For item (the current word being processed)
      V(   Substring instruction
        ⋒  For iterator (the thing the current for loop is iterating through, in this case the current word)
        ∈  For counter
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Given a quick read of the esolangs page (https://esolangs.org/wiki/APOL) and the corresponding interpreter, I do not think you can claim a score of 23 bytes. I do not see any implementation of an appropriate custom code page, which means the program actually deals with unicode characters. Correct me if I'm wrong, and somehow have missed this implementation detail, but it seems this would actually be *31 bytes*. For reference, Jelly implements such a custom codepage, which you can read on here: https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/blob/master/jelly/interpreter.py

Comment: @ConorO'Brien I'm unsure how to do this. Could you explain how to do this?

Comment: Sure. The reason why golfing languages can claim scores like that is because they have the ability to actually read the bytes of a file, and associate those bytes with particular characters. So, your interpreter has to be able to read a file of bytes, and index them into your desired unicode string, and then you can proceed as normal. Here's an example that should help: https://gist.github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/0b5c41012830279b5ba109d9f60aec4f . Note that you want to generate the raw file, e.g., with `with open("sample.txt","wb") as f: f.write(b"\x10\x11")`.

Comment: You probably also want to have a way to convert your unicode to the byte values for ease of access of testing. Probably best done with command line arguments or perhaps as a REPL command

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Okay, I've done it.

Answer (score 2):

## [Mathematica (Wolfram Language)](https://www.wolfram.com/): 71 Characters

```
(a=Characters@#;StringJoin@Array[a[[#;;]] &,Length@a])&/@StringSplit[#]&
```

[TIO Link](https://tio.run/##LcsxCgIxEEbh3lP8bGBREDxAECJ2YiFsOUwxrGETyCYyDoinj1tYv@@tYimuYnmW3h@aq9FecMY1icpsUd/BeUy2leXWcg0XVfmSEDl4z4zxiHusi6UgfMCIU8AO/2F6lWzkNkRDiqU0fJqW58Dc@w8)

There pretty much has to be a better solution than this, but it works.

Explanation:

Takes a string and splits on spaces/newlines/punctuation, then iterates over this list. Finds a list of characters of each "word", then uses the Array to take all the elements, then all but the first, and so on. Then, these are joined (taking advantage of the fact that StringJoin ignores nested lists) and the function moves to the next word.

Answer (score 1):

## C (gcc), 94 bytes

```
f(char*s){char*e=s+strlen(s),*i=s;for(;i<e;*i++=*i-32?*i:0);for(i=s;i<e;i++)printf(*i?i:" ");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY27DsMgDEXn5CssJh6J1McWgrL2Dzq0HSJKUkuUVBB1ifLtFFAn@/oc@ep21jrGierX6HlgW5lGBRFWb42jgTUcVZDT4qnE3kiOQiiO7fk0cOwOrJBsZJgY@3h060Q5DtgRIEzuMR3gPaKjeRn9rBvIPcB5Cl8GW12lL1AwgoKjTKMvpgQhsBjVRLN9wweTKf1ryN2RnPd6j/FirF3gunj7/AE)

Saves a pointer to the end of the string in `char *e`, then replaces spaces with null characters, then prints the string starting with each character and ending at the next null character, but printing a space if the current character is a null character.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 88 bytes

```javascript
f=s=>s.split(' ').map(e=>[...e].map((_,i,a)=>a.slice(i,a.length).join``).join``).join` `
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XccxDsMgDADAr7BhpNQ/gLk/6FBVBREnJXIxilG@T6uMmU63pSNp3kvrtyozjbF49UFRG5cO1liH39SAfHgiIr3OwXsqU3I@JFQumeA/ZKpr/zjcpNQYL5o4slQVJmRZYQF7J2YxD9l5ts6NHw)

Comment: By using `flatMap` you would save a join.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG.

Comment: @tsh throws error: flatMap is not a function
https://tio.run/##XcgxDsMgDEDRq7BhpNQ3gLlL5w5VVSxiUiIXo4B6fZq509f7O32pp6O0cam68pzZdx869iZlgDXW4YcasA8PROQnZqFxOw@8lrKQ84GwS0kMp1C4buPtcNdSY/yriTNp7SqMohtksFcWUXPXQ1br3PwB

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 64 bytes

```c
f(s,t)char*s,*t;{for(;*s;t+=*s<33)for(strcpy(t,s++);*t&31;t++);}
```

Take two char* parameters: The first one for input, and the second one for output. The caller is responsible for malloc and free. Like most string functions in C, this one is designed to be vulnerable by overflow the buffer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hcxNCsIwEAXgfU8xdCFJGkGtCyF6EnER09QW0h9mpoKUnj22qEvp7s2bj@e2D@diLAVplq6yqEgrNmPZoTCKDGcXRec8l0tBjK5/CdaUZdIo3uT7GcxxinXL0Ni6FTIZE4BlCdDTEPh62B1PNzOXpUgrH0KX6u9LGugHJvG7PqYOAbwPKypY8gh3yyuusMgVPG3h8b@c4hs)

Answer (score 1):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 24 characters

```
<L>=@x{$0}
x:?*=?*@x{$2}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ gema '<L>=@x{$0};x:?*=?*@x{$2}' <<< 'darth vader'
dartharthrththh vaderaderdererr
```

Comment: I assume it's the same amount of bytes, unless there's multi-byte characters in there?

Comment: Definitely the same. Gema doesn't use multi-byte characters.

Comment: Okay. It was just strange that you used the term `characters` in the header

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <strike>67</strike> 66 bytes

```
func[s][foreach w split s" "[until[prin w take w tail? w]prin" "]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcoxDsMgEETR3qcYcYw0blOnRRRrs8goK7CWdTg@sVNErubraZTjeHH0YUqPkY6y@hZ8qsq0buhou2RDc3D@KJbF75rL6UZv/k2WGT1cen5CGFcZEtyTRSp6VYlu@msWAbPcRKixYiG7WSS1DR@KrG58AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## Kotlin, 87 bytes

```java
fun f(s:String):String=if(s=="")s else s.split(" ").joinToString(" "){it+f(it.drop(1))}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG; nice first post. You could add a link to an online implementation (like [TIO](https://tio.run/##LYxBCsIwEEXX9hRjoDKDEHBb0kDPoBcI2JTRmIQkLqT27LG0rv7n8f5/huLY12rfHizm7loS@4n@2fPK@l4IyjC6PEKWOTouKECQfAT2t7CbG5m5nC1ykfcUIl6Ilu33ZdijSVPuYEjJfNQ@0QRzc4hrLc6jRaGV0hpO37Y9CqJmqT8)) for ease of verifying your solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 55 bytes

```python
for x in input():
 y=""
 while x:y+=x;x=x[1:]
 print y,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SKFCITMPiApKSzQ0rbgUKm2VlLgUyjMyc1IVKqwqtW0rrCtsK6INrWK5FAqKMvNKFCp1/v9X8kjNyclX0lEKzy/KSVECAA)

Takes input as a list. output is separated by spaces.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 131 bytes

```java
char[]e(char[]a){int b=0,l=a.length,c,d=0;char[]n=new char[l*(l+1)/2];for(;b<l;b++){for(c=l-b;c>0;c--){n[d]=a[l-c];d++;}}return n;}
```

I know there is a better Java answer but, wanted to do it just with char arrays

```java
char[] e(char[]a){
    int b=0,l=a.length,c,d=0;      //l to keep length, b for each iteration, c for each letter in iteration 
    char[] n= new char[l*(l+1)/2]; //Create new array with length based in triangular number sequence
    for(;b<l;b++) {
        for(c=l-b;c>0;c--) {
            n[d]=a[l-c];          //Fill it
            d++;                   //d keeps position in new array
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: `l+1` can most likely be `-~l`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.7](http://julialang.org/), <s>75</s> 65 bytes

```julia
p(a)=for i in a for j=1:endof(i) print(i[j:end])end;print(" ")end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0//@/QCNR0zYtv0ghUyEzTyFRAcTMsjW0Ss1LyU/TyNRUKCjKzCvRyIzOAgnFagIJa4iQkoISiAc0IVrJIzUnJx8oEJ5flJOiFKv5/z8A)

First codegolf. Yay
v0.7 becase it it just deprecates the `endof` method and 1.0 replaces it with `lastindex`.

Update: As mentioned in the comments I am not sure if an array of words as input is permitted. So I included the bytes to take a string as input

Update2: Apparently an array of strings is ok so here we go down to 65 bytes. Thx to @JonathanFrech for removing some more whitespace

Comment: I do not think taking a string array is valid. Please reflect splitting in your byte count.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Yeah I'm not sure too. I just added the 7 more bytes to take a String as the argument.

Comment: You can [remove some whitespace](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0//@/QCNR0zYtv0ghUyEzT6G4ICezBCgCEsiyNbRKzUvJT9PI1FQoKMrMK9HIjM4CCcVqAglriJCSghKIBzRHySM1JydfITy/KCdFSfP/fwA).

Comment: @JonathanFrech oh thanks didn't know that you don't need the white spaces after). In the comments of the golf somebody asked if a list of words would be alright. And the author permitted that. One could argue that an array of words could count as a list. So my first answer would be alright.

Comment: @johnathan Actually the OP has commented that taking/returning a list of words is valid

Comment: @JoKing nice I will update my answer tomorrow when I'm on my pc again

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 48 bytes

Lambda takes a `List<String>` as input and returns a `List<String>` as output, which is allowed. The extra code in the footer is just so the input can be tested easily.

```
{it.map{it.indices.fold(""){a,v->a+it.drop(v)}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU5LDoIwEN1zigmraRQOQATjzgU7TVw3tOhoaUmpJIZw9tqiRt5mkveb9zBOkfbtU0PHSSO316GAg7X8tTs5S/paMZgSCBi5AtncTAFY0@D@clbBmoDST@TyjvfxkBbUyCFvjRKYpmzi2zGr@CZIwpoeRzbPs//1q9ADJaCVXNSkJTLYFxBiy4KIfOgVOUzhy/Xhp8O4C2N4Zbwb0mfzGbX4WTL7o1TKwMVYJd4)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 23 bytes

```
" "/{{""=!}{(;}/}/]" "*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X0lBSb@6WknJVrG2WsO6Vr9WPxYopPX/f0ZqTk6@QgkQZaQqlOcX5aQAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Multi User Forth(121 bytes), Protomuck variant.

```
" " explode_array { swap foreach nip { swap  begin dup 1 strcut nip dup not until }cat repeat }list " " array_join .tell
```

I guess if you want to require that I use entirely standard stuff, then `.tell` it becomes `me @ swap notify` which brings it up to 132 bytes. If you want to go the other direction, then I guess that swap could become `.s` and nip `.n`, dup `.d` etc, would turn it into

```
" " explode_array { .s foreach .n { .s  begin .d 1 strcut .n .d not until }cat repeat }list " " array_join .tell
```

Which has 113 bytes.

Luckily we can continue further, begin turns into `.b`, until `.u` and explode_array `.e`, if we use our thinking caps we can turn foreach into `.f` by defining that into `foreach nip` (who needs the index of the array anyway?) and we end at 94 bytes.

```
" " .e { .s .f { .s  begin .d 1 strcut .n .d not until }cat repeat }list " " array_join .tell
```

But, this is getting silly, and probably only hurting any chance of this being seen as a meaningful first post on codegolf.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), `-DT=t=strtok` `-DZ=" ")` <s>178</s> <s>113</s> <s>106</s> <s>105</s> <s>95</s> 91 bytes

```c
i;f(*a){char*t;for(T(a,Z;t;printf(Z,T(0,Z)for(i=0;t[i];)printf(t+i++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcxNDoIwEIbhNZyi6arlJ2E/6c4jsCohZqwUG7GYMrohXN1ajGE3T94vY2ozoR9jdGBFgXI1NwwFgZ2DaAVWGgiewXmyQletaCot9@RUA9S5HuQ/UunKUsIWk9gDnRfv2V3lmmf7QzbhMoTzBanrmWL8R5bIIc@sOKpMDAO9gmcN5Fs8dh9jJxyXWJ@04ozLdLSK1EKB5vsX)

Comment: This will potentially fail on input longer than \$99\$ bytes. This is not a platform limitation, but your choice. I do not know if this is a valid answer.

Comment: @JonathanFrech but a dynamically growing array to store input would be much longer code. The only other solution would be passing the input as an argument to the function.

Comment: Cool that that is also shorter; as I said -- I do not know if the other is invalid; only that it seemed a bit unelegant.

Comment: Suggest `T(i=0,Z)for(;` instead of `T(0,Z)for(i=0;`

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 81 bytes

```scala
def x(l:String):String=if(l=="")" "else l+x(l.tail)
println(args.map(x).mkString)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcwxDsIwDEbhnVNYmRIh9QBIHTgAEydwidsG/qZRYkElxNlNh05v@fTag8G2Dk95KN04ZZJNJcdG11Loa1FG2jwud60pT@Fon0aPvncuOHKCJoTzrjrlhHAqO1Fkz3Vq3cLFb6FbXsfBfmazAKt91opoCTARGLhJtYHVIled7c1R6h8)

Comment: Taking input as a predefined variable is [not allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8731/76162). That would turn the submission into a snippet. Submissions should either be a full program or a function.

Comment: Hello, @JoKing, thanks. I updated the answer. Does this follow the rules now?

Comment: If you're submitting ot as a full program, I'm afraid you're going to have to include the boilerplate as well

Answer (score 1):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 122 bytes

```
a = ["Hello","World"]
f = fn n,f -> if(n != "") do "#{n}#{f.(String.slice(n, 1..-1), f)}" end end
Enum.map(a, &(f.(&1,f)))

# OUTPUT
["Helloellolloloo", "Worldorldrldldd"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcuxCoMwFEbh3af4ewVJIAZ8AN0KdurQoUPpIJpbAvFG1ELB@uypHc7ywXHBf/ycUocaD2pdCJEM3eMcBnpmfCgLxDDKBp6V4FSDSGOIoHyTPd/Yqts6e3nZJfjeKTGorC0rbcB6JzgZ/mVneY927CbVGRTquIrKsNY6fRtcrtbLMrl@TT8)

Comment: Hi, welcome to PPCG! The input doesn't have to be in the actual code, so you can declare the list in the input section, and reference it by a single letter variable.

Comment: @AlexGrigore Actually, taking input as a predefined variable is [not allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8731/76162). That would turn the submission into a [snippet](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419/76162). Submissions should either be a full program or a function.

Comment: The input shouldn't be hard-coded, but passed to the program/function. You can see what IO methods are allowed [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/76162).

Answer (score 1):

[Kotlin Android](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/)**, 204 bytes**

```
fun f(s:String){ val a=s.split(" ".toRegex()).dropLastWhile{it.isEmpty()}.toTypedArray();for(i in a.indices){var t=0;while(t<a[i].length){for(j in t until a[i].length){print(a[i][j]+"")};t++};print(" ")}
```

}

[Try online](https://rextester.com/live/OUS22695)

This Program is written in Kotlin Android.

Comment: @Keeta, Thank you for your Update.

Comment: Input should not be taken as a predefined variable otherwise this becomes a snippet. Submissions should be a full program or a function equivilant.

Comment: Updated my code.

Comment: Err, the program should take the word as input, not jard code "hello world"

Comment: Updated my code.

Answer (score 1):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <s>42</s> 37+2 bytes

```
s:\b:_:g
:A
s:_(.(\w*_))|__:\1\2:g
tA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v9gqJskq3iqdy8qRq9gqXkNPI6ZcK15TsyY@3irGMMYIKFPi@P9/RmpOTr5CbqVCeX5RTsq//IKSzPy84v@6RQA)

Repeatedly match parts of words between underscores:

```
_hello_ _world_
hello_ello_ world_orld_
helloello_llo_ worldorld_rld_
helloellollo_lo_ worldorldrld_ld_
helloellollolo_o_ worldorldrldld_d_
helloellolloloo__ worldorldrldldd__
helloellolloloo worldorldrldldd
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript(ES6), 34 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.map(k=x=>x?x+k(x.slice(1)):x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgDADQ47hRCf0G1kGij2UrKlNpEru9vXfRR@LfM5cupo3r7qq4UexDGW6nbtRJmxvUSjg9Q484KFafoqTANqQDdphNIOHXtGalYhbE@gM)

Takes input as array of words, returns array of words.

Aaah, the power of recursion...

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <del>46</del> 42 bytes

*-4 thanks to Redwolf*

```javascript
w=>w.split` `.map(f=a=>a&&a+f(a.slice(1)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclLCoAgEADQq4iLGImEdm30LA1@ypgaSdHjW2/7LmxY3JtyXdo2Rje265Ip1V3s@sYM0aCxOE04R0BdKLkAq1JqOH4KU9DEB3iQZyBi0fklL//9AA)

Comment: -2: `d=w=>w.split\` \`.map(f=a=>a&&a+f(a.slice(1)))` (and then you don't need to do the `d=` according to site rules, so another -2)

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 4 bytes

```
∾∘↓¨
```

Anonymous tacit function that takes and returns a list of strings. [Run it online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oi+4oiY4oaTwqgKCkYg4p+oImNhdCIsICJoZWxsbyLin6k=)

#### Explanation

```
∾∘↓¨
   ¨  For each element of the list:
  ↓     Get a list of its suffixes
 ∘      and
∾       join them into one string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `Ṡ`, 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
€ṣṃ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faHm00sOdC5RiFywtLUnTtVj5qGnNw52LH-5sXlKclFwMFV2wKVopJbGoJENJR0GpLDEltUgpFiIDAA)

Input as a list of words. Output as a single string.

##### Explanation

```python
€ṣṃ  # Implicit input
€ṣ   # Suffixes of each string in the list
  ṃ  # Reverse each inner list
     # Implicit output, joined
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `grouping.extras`, 46 bytes

```
[ " "split [ tail-clump concat ] map " "join ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcuxDsIwDATQvV9xyg4fAAsbYmFBTFUHk5picJPguIi/Ly3bne7dnaJnm6@X0/m4w2B5KpKGLX/dqKLye@IUueLFllghGbWouC8I@6YJogpmDU1Qqmy4kS@5J/MHPtSzhblFQPi/0MJJdBN1GgtiTpEcHUYqK3lmSehmNzkssJikdVzr/AM)

Answer (score 0):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 52 bytes

```
s/[a-z]+/@&/g
:l
s/@([a-z]([a-z]+))/\1@\2/
tl
s/@//g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JckxCoAwDEDRPafoJIqUoKNTF0@hDsWGKgQrbVXw8EbQ5Q/vJ3Lab4dIwsHqe6rRFOihY0hoyo/@1lWFY2PGFiF/E9GLLMQc1BUiO1iZFRGDszEv6rSOIsw2P2HPa9iS6P4F)